# LOBs in BerkeleyDB

Tags: java, berkeley-db, lob

what's the usual way to store a CLOB (a few 100KB) inside Berkeley DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley Database doesn't really do datatypes, it stores bytes. So just store your bytes in the database.